# Hibernate generic DAO, Generic Service, and Generic View Layer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been trying to fully understand and implement a GenericDAO layer in hibernate. I am new to the concept and have been doing a bit of reading and studying. I have found numberous examples on example implementations of a GenericDAO Layer, and this is what I have ended up with.

```
public class GenericDAOImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDAO<T, ID> {

    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(GenericDAOImpl.class.getName());


    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T findById(long id, Class<T> objectClass) {
        log.info("Entered GenericDAOImpl findById(" + id +")");
        T result = (T) getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().load(objectClass, id);
        if(result != null){
            Hibernate.initialize(result);
            return result;
        }else{ 
            return null;
        }
    }

    public boolean create(T newInstance) {
        log.info("Entered GenericDAOImpl create()");
        if(newInstance == null){
            return false;
        }
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(newInstance);
        return true;        
    }


    public boolean updpate(T updateInstance) {
        log.info("Entered GenericDAOImpl updpate()");
        if(updateInstance == null){
            return false;
        }
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().update(updateInstance); 
        return true;
    }

    public boolean delete(T entity) {
        log.info("Entered GenericDAOImpl delete()");
        if(entity == null){
            return false;
        }
        getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().delete(entity);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<T> findByExample(T exampleInstance, Class<T> objectClass){
        log.info("Entered GenericDAOImpl findByExample()");
        Criteria searchCriteria = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createCriteria(objectClass);

        searchCriteria.add(Example.create(exampleInstance));

        return (List<T>)searchCriteria.list();          

    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }       
}
```

It seems as though this should work in theory (may need some tweaking)

My question is can I use a generic `service` and `view layer` to "pass through" the layered architecture approach? I do not fully understand hibernate transactions enough to know if it is safe to do this, with its handling of transactions etc...

Maybe something like this for the service layer for example

```
public class GenericServiceImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericService<T, ID>{

    private GenericDAO<T, ID> genericDao;

    @Override
    public T findById(long id, Class<T> objectClass) {
        return this.getGenericDao().findById(id, objectClass);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean create(T newInstance) {
        return this.getGenericDao().create(newInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean updpate(T updateInstance) {
        return this.getGenericDao().updpate(updateInstance);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean delete(T entity) {
        return this.getGenericDao().delete(entity);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public List findByExample(T exampleInstance, Class<T> objectClass) {
        return this.getGenericDao().findByExample(exampleInstance, objectClass);
    }


    public GenericDAO<T, ID> getGenericDao() {
        return genericDao;
    }

    public void setGenericDao(GenericDAO<T, ID> genericDao) {
        this.genericDao = genericDao;
    }


}
```

Then could I go on and do a generic view layer as well?

Please let me know if this approach is acceptable or if there are any concerns with this approach.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and responses!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your service, as it stands, is simply delegating everything to the underlying DAO.  This may be desired sometimes, but typically I put "business logic" in the service layer.  Putting logic in the service layer will help keep your controller layer pretty light too.

A service can use one or more DAOs to accomplish the task it needs.  So consider a simple bank system, where I have a AccountDao

```
public class AccountDao implements GenericDao<Account, Long> {
  // your save, insert, delete, find, etc
}
```

Then in my service, I would put "makePayment" or something

```
@Service
public class AccountService {

   @Autowired
   private AccountDao dao;

   @Transactional
   public void makePayment(Long fromId, Long toId, double amount) {
      Account from = dao.find(fromId);
      from.withdrawl(amount);

      Account to = dao.find(toId);
      to.deposit(amount);

      dao.save(from);
      dao.save(to);
   }
}
```

Use transactions on your service layer, to give you more control over which operations need to be in the same transaction.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! So just to clarify, You would still create a separate DAO for each hibernate domain object that would simply implement or extend the GenericDAO? The whole purpose of me creating the genericDAO was to reduce the number of redundant hibernate DAO classes ?

Comment: If your database operations are this simple (just update, insert, delete) and no specialized queries, then you can just instantiate several generic daos, one for each type.

Answer (score 4):

I have implemented a Generic Entity, Dao and Service for Hibernate

**BaseEntity**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -932093556089251203L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

**GenericDao**

```
public interface GenericDao<T, ID extends Serializable> {

    T save(T entity);
    T update(T entity);
    void delete(T entity);
    T findById(long id);
    List<T> findAll();
    void flush();
}
```

**GenericJpaDao**

```
@Transactional
public abstract class GenericJpaDao<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> persistentClass;

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public GenericJpaDao(Class<T> persistentClass) {
        this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
    }

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
        return persistentClass;
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public T findById(long id) {
        T entity = (T) getEntityManager().find(getPersistentClass(), id);
        return entity;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return getEntityManager()
            .createQuery("select x from " + getPersistentClass().getSimpleName() + " x")
            .getResultList();
    }

    public T save(T entity) {
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);
        return entity;
    }

    public T update(T entity) {
        T mergedEntity = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
        return mergedEntity;
    }

    public void delete(T entity) {
        if (BaseEntity.class.isAssignableFrom(persistentClass)) {
            getEntityManager().remove(
                    getEntityManager().getReference(entity.getClass(), 
                            ((BaseEntity)entity).getId()));
        } else {
            entity = getEntityManager().merge(entity);
            getEntityManager().remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public void flush() {
        getEntityManager().flush();
    }

}
```

**GenericService**

```
public class GenericService<T, ID extends Serializable> {
    @Autowired
    private GenericDao<T, ID> genericDao;

    public T find(long id) {
        return this.getGenericDao().findById(id);
    }

    public List<T> all() {
        return this.getGenericDao().findAll();
    }

    @Transactional
    public T create(T newInstance) {
        return (T) this.getGenericDao().save(newInstance);
    }

    @Transactional
    public T updpate(T updateInstance) {
        return (T) this.getGenericDao().update(updateInstance);
    }

    @Transactional
    public void delete(T entity) {
         this.getGenericDao().delete(entity);
    }

    public GenericDao<T, ID> getGenericDao() {
        return genericDao;
    }

    public void setGenericDao(GenericDao<T, ID> genericDao) {
        this.genericDao = genericDao;
    }


}
```

**For Use :**

**User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6189512849157712745L;

    @Column(name="username", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @Column(name="name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**UserDAO**

```
public interface UserDAO extends GenericDao<User, Long> {


}
```

**UserDAOImpl**

```
@Repository
public class UserDAOImpl extends GenericJpaDao<User, Long>  implements UserDAO {

    public UserDAOImpl() {
        super(User.class);
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

}
```

**And Finally the Magic Service my Service Mysv**

```
@Service
public class Mysv extends GenericService<User, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information, there exists a separate code library for GenericDAO [hibernate-generic-dao](https://code.google.com/p/hibernate-generic-dao/)! Its always good to write your own code for the purpose of learning, but I believe its also important to read code of standard libary and frameworks to learn standards that has been adopted there by experts. So, it is recommended to visit this library.