# Generic DAO why us generic type Id

Tags: java, hibernate, generics, dao

i did look at a lot DAO examples, and i do "always" see that these generic DAOs always have the generic type ID which extends from Serializable. But this type is never used in the class? So what is the background behind this, or is it still a copy/paste issue from tutorial to tutorial ? Hope to get some response, thx

Generic implemention from a DAO with java and hibernate:
[Hibernate generic DAO, Generic Service, and Generic View Layer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12099213/hibernate-generic-dao-generic-service-and-generic-view-layer?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I almost never use a generic Type ID in my generic DAO's. It is totally fine to use just

```
public abstract GenericDao<T> {
    /**
     * Method that returns the number of entries from a table that meet some
     * criteria (where clause params)
     *
     * @param params
     *            sql parameters
     * @return the number of records meeting the criteria
     */
    long countAll(Map<String, Object> params);

    T create(T t);

    void delete(Object id);

    T find(Object id);

    T update(T t);   
}
```

BUT it is practice to define a primary key other than long ID in this case:

```
public abstract GenericDAO<T, PK implements Serializable>
```

read up here for a detailed Information [Don't repeat the DAO](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-genericdao/)

Comment: What if someone uses a non-serializable object?

Comment: JPA specification contains such a requirement (JSR-317 secion 2.4 Primary Keys and Entity Identity): You should read up on JPA, in several situations it will work without serialization but in some cases it won't. Buzzword: "remote interface"

Comment: Shouldn't it be   T find(Serializable id);  instead of T find(Object id);

Comment: Depends on your Primary key, it will work in the same way. If you use just Long ID you can use find(Object id) if you use a composite key you should use T find(PK id).

Answer (score 1):

Id type should be used in declaration of `find()` (or any other methods that accept id):

```
public abstract class GenericDao<E, ID extends Serializable> {
   ...
   public E find(ID id) { ... }
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, that means that this example and much other in the net is not 100% correct? but why this ID must be serializable? is the serializable value stored in the DB, when yes why?

Comment: If you declare a generic type ID extends serializable I will expect that all methods should use it when applicable. As axtavt says: find(ID id) instead of find(Object id) or find(Long id).

Nobody force you to use generics for your ID but if you do it, be coherent. In my opinion those internet examples work but could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

I may be just a case of translating the Hibernate API.

There are some functions that use serializable IDs. Programmers might have thought that there was no need to restrict the potential of it's generic DAO. See for example [get](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#get%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) and [load](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#load%28java.lang.Class,%20java.io.Serializable%29) methods. They have the same serializable ID:

```
Object load(Class theClass,
            Serializable id)
            throws HibernateException
```

But, as others have said, you are free to use a fixed type like a Long for your IDs. At least if you are sure that you are not going to use a String as a primary key. (Example: a country could have the ISO Code as its primary key).